# If Row contains blank then concat to row above then delet

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Would Genuinely appreciate some assistance pls.
Ultimately, I would like to find the last row with a blank cell (Column A or B) then Concat/write the information from Column C in same row to the row above and delete the row it has found.
I have found the CODE to allow the VBA to find and delete last row but cannot work out how to CONCAT/write the information to line above.   Any thoughts help would be amazing thank you.

Code so far:

```
Application.calculation = xlcalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set WS as Long
Lrow = WS.UsedRange.Rows(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

Dim i as Long
For i = Lrow To 1 Step -1

If ws.Cells(i, 4) = "" Then
ws.Rows(i).Delete
End If

Next i

Application.calculation = xlcalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're choosing what to concatenate, as I'm not seeing any code specific to that, you would be able to utilize the following as an example:

```
dim concatenatedString as string
concatenatedString = ws.cells(i,1).value & " " & ws.cells(i+1,1).value
```

Be wearing using `i-1` because your `For` loop ends on `1`, leading to a `0` row and errors.

Comment: Thank you Cyril.   Have attempted to use the additional lines of code but unable to Concat information (either with the Line delete code present or removed)  I am very new to coding so possibly my error.